# Zabbix web не соединяется с БД

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, zabbix

Установил на виртуальный сервер zabbix 6.2. В качестве хранилища MySQL 8.0.31. На виртуальной машине стоит Ubuntu 22.04. Все ровно так же как по инструкции https://www.zabbix.com/download?zabbix=6.2&os_distribution=ubuntu&os_version=22.04&components=server_frontend_agent&db=mysql&ws=apache. Пароли и в /etc/zabbix/zabbix_server.conf, и в /etc/zabbix/web/zabbix.conf.php одинаковы

```
DBName=zabbix
DBUser=zabbix
DBPassword=10xx83
```

```
$DB['TYPE']                     = 'MYSQL';
$DB['SERVER']                   = 'localhost';
$DB['PORT']                     = '0';
$DB['DATABASE']                 = 'zabbix';
$DB['USER']                     = 'zabbix';
$DB['PASSWORD']                 = '10xX83';
```

В логах ошибок нет, все запускается нормально, но при попытке зайти на http://localhost/zabbix выдает следующую ошибку и дальше не идет

[image: Ошибка яфиишч]

***UPDATE***

```
/**
     * Create connection to database server.
     *
     * @param string $host         Host name.
     * @param string $port         Port.
     * @param string $user         User name.
     * @param string $password     Password.
     * @param string $dbname       Database name.
     * @param string $schema       DB schema.
     *
     * @return mysqli|null
     */
    public function connect($host, $port, $user, $password, $dbname, $schema): ?mysqli {
        mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
        print_r($host, $port, $user, $password, $dbname, $schema);
        $resource = mysqli_init();

        if ($resource === false) {
            return null;
        }

        if ($this->tls_encryption) {
            $cipher_suit = $this->tls_cipher_list !== '' ? $this->tls_cipher_list : null;
            $resource->ssl_set($this->tls_key_file, $this->tls_cert_file, $this->tls_ca_file, null, $cipher_suit);

            $tls_mode = MYSQLI_CLIENT_SSL;
        }
        else {
            $tls_mode = 0;
        }

        try {
            @$resource->real_connect($host, $user, $password, $dbname, $port, null, $tls_mode);
        }
        catch (mysqli_sql_exception $e) {
            $this->setError($e->getMessage());

            return null;
        }

        if ($resource->autocommit(true) === false) {
            $this->setError('Error setting auto commit.');

            return null;
        }

        return $resource;
    }
```

***Решение***
Все таки в /etc/zabbix/web/zabbix.conf.php был неверно вбит пароль, после правки все заработало

Comment: [дубликаты](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmysql%5D+access+denied)

Comment: Не дубликаты, так как именно к MySQL через cli я подключаюсь нормально не работает именно через веб-интерфейс zabbix. При чем до этого все получилось, но при переустановке опять проблема возникла, вроде уже все перепробовал - решения пока не нашел

Comment: *именно к MySQL через cli я подключаюсь нормально* Проверь, как именно подключаешься - действительно по IP, или через сокет/пайп/память. И вообще, включен ли доступ к MySQL по IP (skip-networking). Ну и просмотра логов MySQL никто не отменял..

Comment: По поводу логов я уже говорил - они пустые, картинку с пустым логом могу выслать из /var/log/mysql/error.log

Comment: По поводу соединения сейчас добавлю код

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в неправильно вбитом пароле в файле /etc/zabbix/web/zabbix.conf.php